# Google Map displays with no errors in console but weird code also displays?

Tags: google-maps

I have an issue with some strange code displaying above a google map. The same code that typically appears if there is an error loading the map.

I do not have any error in the console and I really do not understand what would be the cause or cure of such issue. I hope someone can shed some light on this please.

I have searched around online and can not find anything on this. Please see image below or at https:mavericksondarby.com.au

Thanks[see code displaying above map here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0SEy.png)

Comment: pictures don't help.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: Do mean a live example of the issue? Can be found here, thanks https://mavericksondarby.com.au

Comment: No, I mean a [mcve] in the question itself, not (just) a link to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following style from https://mavericksondarby.com.au/assets/css/eleganticons.css is responsible

```
[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

The map div has a following attribute `data-icon="assets/images/map-icon.png"`. So you apply this style to maps div.

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution...

Add to css file this code:

```
div#map:before {
display: none;
}
```

and the code is no longer displayed. Much thanks to Sergey the legend!